# Connect Linux to Mac Samba (Windows like sharing)

Tags: lubuntu, samba, mac

Hello I want to create samba share folder between Linux (Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS) and Mac OS X (v 10.7.5) but this is what I get from a command:

```
smbclient -L //192.168.1.18/
```

Output:

```
Enter mareeke's password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Darwin] Server=[@(#)PROGRAM:smbd  PROJECT:smbx-105.8.70]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
IPC$            IPC       
Jon Johnson's Public Folder Disk      
Music           Disk      
mareeke         Disk      
Connection to 192.168.1.18 failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
NetBIOS over TCP disabled -- no workgroup available
```

I know something about NetBIOS but it is Windows thing... so what to do if I am using windows sharing without Windows box?

Comment: Have you created a share yet? If so, then where? Is it created on OSX, or on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I am sharing "Music" folder on MAC so I created account for access on MAC (readonly) and command upthere give that output.

Comment: So what does it have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: Eh... I cant access share folder with ubuntu... so you tell me problem is in Mac ya?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the result I receive from my Mac as well to that command, `smbclient -L 192.168.1.111` (my Mac's IP).

**If you want to access your shared music from your Mac to use or play back on Lubuntu, I would suggest using PCManFM, Lubuntu's File Manager, instead.**

From your File Manager (which you can access by clicking on the Folder icon on your taskbar, or in System Tools > File Manager PCManFM)

Then, you can type in the address bar:

```
smb://192.168.1.18
```

(if 192.168.1.18 is your Mac's IP address).

---

If you'd rather use the GUI way, you can do instead:

- Select "Go" > "Network"
- Double-click "Windows Network".
- Double-click the name of your domain (Probably "WORKGROUP")
- Find and double-click on the name of your Mac.

---

At this point, you'll need to enter the password for your Mac's account.

[image: Enter the password for your Mac account]

Once you've successfully entered your password, the folders shared from your Mac will be listed.

[image: List of Mac shares]

Double-click on your Music share, and find the song you want to play.

[image: Music listed, playing.]

Comment: Work like a charm man! I was trying `smb://192.168.1.18` in browser :D but in PCmanFM "pathbar" i didnt try... THANKS! :)

Comment: How do i find the domain name? in your example it WORKGROUP

Comment: Lovely Lubuntu, thanks for your great answer.

Comment: @AhmedRana - it should be identified in samba's configuration file. By default that file is located in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`
it will be defined in that file as the variable workgroup, ie. `workgroup = WORKGROUP`